# Integrating react-native With Existing Apps

Tags: react-native, stetho

`com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0` 
of react native conflict with my existing project components :

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
```

the error:

```
Error:Module 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.2.0' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar
```

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cn.titaandroid.im"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2017021610
        versionName '0.9.0'

        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            storeFile file('titaandroid.keystory')
            storePassword '123456'
            keyAlias 'tita'
            keyPassword '123456'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config //for release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config //for release
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false

        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
        compile project(':Recognizer')
        compile project(':contactcard')
        compile project(':sticker')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
        compile files('libs/MiPush_SDK_Client_3_1_2.jar')
        compile project(':IMKit')
        compile project(':CallKit')
        compile project(':RedPacket')
        compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I've just downgraded to 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1' and worked.